# Attempt to index number with 'Text' how to fix?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I am trying to make a set of labels which update every 2.5 seconds to the values of player attributes, however my attempt does not work, how can I fix this?

```lua
local StrenghtButton = script.Parent.Frame.Strenght
local DFButton = script.Parent.Frame.DevilFruit
local SwordButton = script.Parent.Frame.Sword

local StrenghtLabel = script.Parent.Frame.StrenghtLabel
local DFLabel = script.Parent.Frame.DFLabel
local SwordLabel = script.Parent.Frame.SwordLabel
local AvaiblePoints = script.Parent.Frame.AttributePointsIndicator
local Frame = script.Parent.Frame

local StatsMenu = script.Parent.StatsMenu

local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local AvaiblePoints = Player:GetAttribute("AvaiblePoints")
local StrenghtValue = Player:GetAttribute("Strenght")
local DFValue = Player:GetAttribute("DevilFruit")
local SwordValue = Player:GetAttribute("Sword")

while true do
    task.wait(2.5)
    AvaiblePoints.Text = "Avaible Points - " .. AvaiblePoints
    StrenghtLabel.Text = "Strenght - " .. StrenghtValue
    DFLabel.Text = "Devil Fruit - " .. DFValue
    SwordLabel.Text = "Sword - " .. SwordValue
end

StrenghtButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if AvaiblePoints >= 1 then
        Player:SetAttribute("Strenght", StrenghtValue+1)
    end
end)

DFButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if AvaiblePoints >= 1 then
        Player:SetAttribute("DevilFruit", DFValue+1)
    end
end)

SwordButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if AvaiblePoints >= 1 then
        Player:SetAttribute("Sword", SwordValue+1)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the same values for your labels in the `while` loop, the values you fetched initially for each attribute is being saved to the same variable that is then being displayed.

Instead of re-using the same variable, you need to `GetAttribute()` each time you render your label to fetch the current value.

```lua
while true do
    task.wait(2.5)
    AvaiblePoints.Text = "Avaible Points - " .. Player:GetAttribute("AvaiblePoints")
    StrenghtLabel.Text = "Strenght - " .. Player:GetAttribute("Strenght")
    DFLabel.Text = "Devil Fruit - " .. Player:GetAttribute("DevilFruit")
    SwordLabel.Text = "Sword - " .. Player:GetAttribute("Sword")
end
```

Comment: I tried using AttributeChanged event, and switch the Variable to Player:GetAttribute("Attribute") but didn't work

Comment: Why use the `AttributeChanged` event? You can just use `GetAttribute()` directly as shown in the code above.

Comment: i switch the while true to AttributeChanged

Comment: Why not just leave it as a while true loop? And just use the code snippet above?

Comment: I delete the while true bc if the Player get 1 more Strenght point for an example, then the Gui Updates.